# Issue with this Junit plugin test code execution :: ServiceReference<?> faUiApiServiceRef = bundleContext .getServiceReference();

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, junit4

I have two plugin-

Inside first plugin Activator class

I am registering service like this -

**public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
Activator.context = bundleContext;
bundleContext.registerService(IFileAidExUiApiService.class, instance, properties);
Environment.getInstance().setUiApiServiceActivated(true);
}**

Inside second plugin Activator class -

```
**@Override
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    super.start(bundleContext);
    ServiceReference<?> faUiApiServiceRef = bundleContext
            .getServiceReference(XYZ.class.getName());
    plugin = this;
}**
```

> ServiceReference<?> faUiApiServiceRef = bundleContext
> .getServiceReference(this.getClass().getName());

**faUiApiServiceRef** this variable always getting **null** in tycho 2.5.0 version.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why that old Tycho version? Does it work in a different Tycho version or when running the test from within Eclipse? What's the purpose of `getServiceReference(this.getClass().getName())` (getting a service reference of itself (`this`)). By the way, better use [`getServiceReference(Class<S> type)`](https://docs.osgi.org/javadoc/osgi.core/7.0.0/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReference-java.lang.Class-), [without `.getName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738674/6505250).

Comment: @howlger Thank you for your response.

I tried this as well, no luck.

Earlier I was using 2.3.0 tycho version.

Comment: Did it work with Tycho 2.3.0? The current Tycho version is [4.0.2](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/releases/tag/tycho-4.0.2). Getting a service reference of itself does not make sense to me. Please explain. Please show a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, its work with tycho 2.3.0.

Comment: @howlger I have updated description, please check. hopefully you will be more clear now.

Again this issue is only if I run Junit plugin testcase, otherwise this is working fine.